# syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in PHP script

Tags: php

I made small search for this error. there are a lot of topics but looks like none of them apply to me. As I see it this code is perfectly fine. Why do I have an error?

```
<ul class="uk-grid uk-text-center" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
        <li class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
            <a href="<?php JRoute::_($cat->link)?>">
                <?php if ($cat->level == 1) :?>
                    <img src="<?php $cat->image;?>" alt="<?php $cat->description; ?>" width="175" height="80">
                <?php else: ?>
                    <img src="<?php $cat->image;?>" alt="<?php $cat->description; ?>" width="135" height="135">
                <? endif;?> 
                <h2 class="uk-article-title">
                    <?php $cat->title; ?>
                </h2>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Here is my php version

```
/var/www/localhost # php -v
PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2021 20:31:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

But I do not think it is a problem because i started from 7.2 and then 7.3 and all gave same result.

Ссылка с ошибкой
http://flareapp.io/share/4m4oEOJ5

Comment: If you don't have shorttags enabled `<? endif;?>` may not be recognised.  Best to use `<?php endif;?>`

Comment: I've change that to `<?php` no affect.

Comment: Seems not reproductible : https://3v4l.org/Tt8P8

Comment: @NicoHaase the link you've provided does not help. I do not want to say I am an expert, but I am quite experienced PHP developer from PHP2FI. I know how to handle syntax errors in general. But I stack with his one.  This error is more a magic than sense to me.

Comment: All your `<?php $cat->title; ?>` don't do nothing. You need either `<?php echo` or `<?=`.

Comment: @deceze Yes, I know. Thank you though. That is because I mas changed `<?=` to `<?php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works well, you forget `php` after `<?` in this line: `<?php endif;?>`

So `<? endif;?>` is wrong and `<?php endif;?>` will work well.

```
<ul class="uk-grid uk-text-center" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
        <li class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
            <a href="<?php JRoute::_($cat->link)?>">
                <?php if ($cat->level == 1) :?>
                    <img src="<?php $cat->image;?>" alt="<?php $cat->description; ?>" width="175" height="80">
                <?php else: ?>
                    <img src="<?php $cat->image;?>" alt="<?php $cat->description; ?>" width="135" height="135">
                <?php endif;?> 
                <h2 class="uk-article-title">
                    <?php $cat->title; ?>
                </h2>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

or if you want to write without `php` word in `<?php` you should do it for all the lines related to `if` statement so your code will be like this: but I recommand to use above code instead of bellow code:

```
<ul class="uk-grid uk-text-center" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
        <li class="uk-width-medium-1-5">
            <a href="<?php JRoute::_($cat->link)?>">
                <? if ($cat->level == 1) :?>
                    <img src="<?php $cat->image;?>" alt="<?php $cat->description; ?>" width="175" height="80">
                <? else: ?>
                    <img src="<?php $cat->image;?>" alt="<?php $cat->description; ?>" width="135" height="135">
                <? endif;?> 
                <h2 class="uk-article-title">
                    <?php $cat->title; ?>
                </h2>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

so if we use `<?` for `if()` statement, we can't use `<?php else:` for else statement. we should use `<? else: ?>` like the `if()` statment

Comment: Thank you. This is not my code; I always use `<?php`. I just try to debug it and I was not seeing or overlooked this error.

Comment: You're always welcome, I'm happy to solve the problem. if you use `php intelephense` extension in `vscode`, you can see the problem, before you debug it.

Comment: I do use this extension, but it only highlighted `<?php endforeach; ?>` with that syntax error. That is because inteliphence uses php executable to Lint files and that php gave endforeach error.

Comment: Note, to use just `<?` you have to enable it  via `short_open_tag` in your php.ini